# iOS Native picker view for sencha touch 2 and phone gap application

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2.2

Is there any way to use the native picker views instead of the ST2 based picker view in the application consisting of ST2 and phonegap.

Comment: Hey your question is not clear? Are you looking for a predefined pickerview for your Application or you want to do a custom design?

Comment: I am not looking for a predefined picker view. ST2 already have a picker view in it but its not native to the OS. i want to show the native picker as per the mobile os as I am generating a build using the phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. If you use the ST2 you can work only with it components.
If you're trying to change the default layout or the position and order of the ST2 Picker, you can put it inside a layout or container. The Picker object is highly adjustable in ST2.